# Angular-Translate : Child Module translatePartialLoader urlTemplate overrides the Parent Module translatePartialLoader urlTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have to use multiple translatePartialLoader with different urlTemnplate. I am using angular-translate-loader-pluggable. It seems like the child module urltemplate overrides the parent modules urltemplate

Parent Module Config

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: __env.hostUrl + '/*****/****/localization/resource_bundle?bundle_name={part}&locale={lang}'
        });
        $translateProvider.useLoader('translatePluggableLoader');
```

Child Module Config

```
 translatePluggableLoaderProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: navigationConfig.rsiDomain + navigationConfig.rsiBaseUrl + navigationConfig.localizationUrl + '?bundle_name={part}&locale={lang}'
        });
```

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at this post: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1627.    You can only have one loader.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want.  By default you can only have one provider.  Take a look at  https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1627